# create xts with equal dates and their values in R

Tags: r

I have seven xts with different row numbers and some different dates. How can I have xts with equal dates and their values in R? i.e. I would like to eliminate the different dates between the xts with their values

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and its expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.